# How to add Opencarto to a Geotools project?

Tags: java, geotools, opencarto

I've installed geotools through maven (and m2ecplise) but I'm not able to add `opencarto` library to my project. (As you can guess, I'm new to java)

I tried by adding `opencarto`'s main folder as library through the Project panel, but still, maven is not proposing me `opencarto` as dependency when I try to find it.

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

(this is probably a question for you Julien. I sent you a mail through sourceforge. I'm not sure you got it ... anyway, it's a good thing to make noise around `opencarto` since it seems very interesting!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maven can only handle libraries that are deployed on a maven repository, and Opencarto is not deployed anywhere, so you cannot get it with maven. To use it, you may use one of these methods:

1. you download an opencarto jar from [there](http://opencarto.sourceforge.net/v/0.9/opencarto.jar) and include it in your eclipse project (you also need [jts](http://opencarto.sourceforge.net/v/0.9/jts-1.11.jar), [xstream](http://opencarto.sourceforge.net/v/0.9/xstream-1.3.1.jar) and [xpp3_min](http://opencarto.sourceforge.net/v/0.9/xpp3_min-1.1.4c.jar))
2. you checkout the snapshot version of opencarto from the SVN as a new eclipse project, and add this project to your project's build path.

Good luck! (and thanks for using my lib - you are the first!)

Comment: Hi Julien,Thanks to you. I try to handle all that new stuff the coming week. By the way, do I need geotools to manipulate shapefiles or is there another lighter alternative?

Comment: Hi! I understood better the way geotools works. Opencarto, is just perfect! Basically, when I asked for the smallest MBR in my other post, it was to perform the first step of Duchene & al algorithm to calculate the general orientation. When I saw that opencarto was doing it I was looking forward to see the result ... I'm quite happy ;-) Thanks again for developing that fantastic lib.