# Building orientation and simplification using Opencarto Java library

Tags: postgis, geometry, java, opencarto

I need to find out orientation of buildings and perform simplification of sides of buildings with a tolerance. I came to know from Stack Exchange that OpenCarto has useful libraries for geometrical functions. Basically i have stored data in PostGIS.

Is there any possibility to use Opencarto Java Library to perform this on buildings?

I think it is possible to connect Java with PostGIS through JDBC driver.

Answer (score 2):

Personnally I did it (general orientation calculation see [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5608/geotools-and-opencarto) and there) from shapefiles using [geotools](http://geotools.org/) library and opencarto. Opencarto's devloper ([Jul](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/162/jul)) could maybe help you, if needed.

[By the way, here you will find a JDBC sample](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ch05.html#id2633989) to retrieve Postgis data.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Will it be possible to use Opencarto library with Netbeans other than eclipse?

Comment: I'm not a java expert, but for sure Opencarto is not dependant to any IDE! Using Netbeans will not cause any issue.

Comment: Thanks for info. I will try Geotools with Netbeans. Please let me know what have you developed with Geotools for orientation?

Comment: I just wanted to know the smallest MBR to get the main orientation of buildings. Opencarto has a native method for that!

Comment: Oh it is very nice. Could you please let me know how to use it. Me too needs to calculate orientation of buildings?

Comment: I can add Opencarto .JAR file to a Java project. Also geotools.jar files to handle .shp file. Please let me know any supporting doc to follow Opencarto methods.

Comment: once you have added the jars, just call the required methods. For geotools, follow up tutorials and examples. Please, do not post into that [question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5608/geotools-and-opencarto/), this is not a forum!